# Can a class be a property of an object? Is this what React.Component is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6

I've been learning about classes and React and came across the React.Component class which you extend to create a class component. I understand that React.Component must be a class if we extend it but then what is the overall `React` part? is it just an object on which Component is a property as a class, since we access it with dot notation? I've not seen examples of objects where a class can be a property in any of my tutorials. Would love to understand this.

Comment: Classes are objects. Objects are objects. Objects have properties. A property can hold any arbitrary value. Including other objects. Including classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes can be referenced and assigned to object property values just like other things.

```js
class Component {}

const React = { Component: Component };

class MyComponent extends React.Component {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think laid out this way it makes sense, I wasn't sure if the class could be defined as a value directly inside the object, I'm not sure if it can but this way is understandable.